# load xy.php page on same div in which earlier ab.php is opened using .load() by getting data-async-load from ab.php button using .load jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, delegates

I don't know whether how to ask that question but the probem is I my using `<a  data-async-load="ab.php"></a>` which open in a div `<div class="portfolio">` when I click on this `<a>` tag ab.php page open successfully. The problem arose when I try to open `xy.php` by clicking on button `<button type="button" data-async-load="xy.php">` than nothing happens. I'm just trying to open that "xy.php" form on the same div  utilizing .load()  method by clicking on the button of already opened `ab.php` by jquery .load() data-async-load in the `<div class="portfolio">`. Any Suggestion ?? ? ? ? Here is the scree shot what I want to accomplish
[image]

In this screenshot you are seeing clearly that Area  Form is opened in div by clickig on `<li><a data-async-load="ab.php"></a></li>`now I want to open a new page called `xy.php` using same .load() method by clicking on Add Ne button `<button type="button" class=" btn btn-info btn-lg" name="btnNewEntry" id="btnNewEntry" value="Add New" 
                data-async-load="xy.php">ADD NEW</button>` How can I achieve this ? ? ?
here is **[ab.php](https://jsfiddle.net/hx2njp6s/)** code
here is my **[main page](https://jsfiddle.net/boqaab3g/)**code
third is xy.php on which i want to go
Here is my button code

```
 <button type="button" class=" btn btn-info btn-lg" name="btnNewEntry" id="btnNewEntry" value="Add New" 
                data-async-load="xy.php"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" style="margin-right: 6px;"></i>ADD NEW</button>
```

Here is my JQuery For `<a>` tag

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
 $('a[data-async-load]').click(function(e) { 
 e.preventDefault(); 
 var externalUrl = $(this).attr('data-async-load'); 
 $('#portfolio').load(externalUrl)
 })
 });
```

Here is my Jquery .load() for button

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
 $("button").click(function(){
alert("hi")
e.preventDefault(); 
var externalUrl = $(this).attr('data-async-load'); 
    $("#portfolio").load(externalUrl);
 })
});
```

**How to call Jquery .load() function on this button from this div which is already open by using .load() jquery call** 
butt seems like for button jquery is not working

**Update1:**
ok know I'm using delegated method in which I'm running the following query to get when a user clicks on `ab.php` add new button but nothing geting worked I don't know where I'm doing the mistake. I wrote that query in my main page

```
 $("div#portfolio button.btnNewEntry").on("click", function() { alert("Hi");});
```

**Update2:**
Ok I successfully run the deligated menthod but the problem is when i click the button than how it will load it in  the following updated jquery. It loads the page but when i click on the buton two times not on single time.

```
 $("div#portfolio").on("click", "#btnNewEntry", function() { alert("Hi");
 $('button[data-async-load]').click(function(e) { 
 e.preventDefault(); 
 var externalUrl = $(this).attr('data-async-load'); 
 $('#portfolio').load(externalUrl)
 })
 });
```

Comment: `<button type="button data-async-load="xy.php"" >` has a syntax error - too many double-quotes ("). I wouldn't use simply "button" as a selector though - then if you add more buttons to the page it'll do that action on all of them. Use an ID or class instead.

Comment: @ADyson I have updated it and take a look again. The problem i'm facing is how to open xy.php page in the same div in which ab.php is loaded and by clicking ab.php button I want to call Jquery .load( ) mehod which than load xy.php page ??? how approach this methodology ?

Comment: look into "delegated" events here: http://api.jquery.com/on/ . Basically you need to write a jQuery event which will bind itself to elements which doesn't exist yet (i.e. the button from ab.php which is not downloaded until later)

Comment: downloaded means that it is not present in the main page where the .load() jquery exist ?

Comment: ok now what I have to do any example @ADyson look at edited question again

Comment: ab.php is downloaded when you press on the `<a>` link, right? So it doesn't exist when the main page is loaded. So if you want to write some script in your main page which responds to a button inside ab.php, then you need to use delegated events, because otherwise at the moment when you bind the "click" event on "button", your button has not been loaded yet. Examples in the "direct and delegated events" section of the link I gave you above. Try it, if you can't make it work then update your question with relevant details of what you did and what errors you get.

Comment: ok @ADyson I'm trying but in my case I first have to bind the  button ?? using jquery in main page when ab.php is loaded ????

Comment: Yes that's what you would need to do, but do it in a delegated way.

Comment: ok I'm writing this but nothing happens function notify() {
  alert( "clicked" );
}
$( "button" ).on( "click", notify );

should I have to add this on main page
$( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
}); ??? 
I'm not getting but I got the your Idea

Comment: I'm not getting you either. It's the _button_ part which needs the delegated. And I don't know what this "notify" function is? Generally it's not a good idea to define event handlers within functions in case they get defined multiple times over and over. Also please edit your question with any extra code etc as it's very difficult to read it in the comments due to lack of formatting.

Comment: ok I'll Edit my question and know I'm using this but nothing get worked up for me ` $("div#portfolio").on("click", "button.btnNewEntry", function() {alert("Hi");});`

Comment: seeing the relevant parts of the HTML in ab.php which you want to bind to would also be helpful. Otherwise we're working blind.

Comment: ok I'll update the code of ab.php

Comment: @ADyson look at the edited question

Comment: `$("div#portfolio button.btnNewEntry").on("click", function() { alert("Hi");});` is not a delegated method. As per the examples (again, in that link I gave you, it's really very clear if you look carefully) the selector you want to delegate to has to be the second argument to the .on method. e.g. `$("div#portfolio").on("click", "#btnNewEntry", function() { alert("Hi");});`. Assuming that `"div#portfolio"` is a part of your main page which exists when the main page loads. P.S. `button.btnNewEntry` won't work because your button doesn't have a class called btnNewEntry. That's it's ID.

Comment: than what should will work for me I'm really very confuse now .....

Comment: @ADyson ok I did it Thanks to you (: Just place it in the end of the page. but in this query how can I get button click to run the load query ?
`$("div#portfolio").on("click", "#btnNewEntry", function() { 
 $('button[data-async-load]').click(function(e) { 
e.preventDefault(); 
var externalUrl = $(this).attr('data-async-load'); 
    $("#portfolio").load(externalUrl);
 })
});`

Comment: now you've got the delegated event, `$('button[data-async-load]').click(function(e) {` makes no sense. It's just your old handler within the new handler. Surely it was obvious you had to replace that with the new version? I feel like you don't actually understand what all these bits of code are for, in which case please study the documentation or tutorials in more depth.

Comment: yes @ADyson you are right I'm new with this working but will get use to . .. by reading. and I did it on that day with your hel (:

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the following code on your main page in which `<div>` is present and `ab.php` is showing in it and earlier on `xy.php` will be shown by clicking on  the **Add New** button

```
 <script> 
  $("div#portfolio").on("click", "#btnNewEntry", function() {// alert("Hi");
  var externalUrl = $(this).attr('data-async-load'); 
  $('#portfolio').load(externalUrl)

 });
 </script>
```

> **Important Note**: ADD that `<script>` on the last of your page